# Color Configuration in xterm

Tags: colorscheme

I have been using NVIM on Ubuntu machine for about 3 month now, and like most noobs started with gnome terminal, I would like to graduate to plain xterm, but having trouble with the color in xterm.  Below, on the left is the gnome terminal and on the right is the xterm:

[image: gnome-terminal vs xterm]

Below is my xterm configuration:

File `~/.xinitrc` contents

```
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge -I$HOME ~/.Xresources
```

File `~/.Xresources` contents

```
xterm*faceName: Ubuntu Mono for Powerline
xterm*faceSize: 11

xterm*loginshell: true

xterm*savelines: 16384

! double-click to select whole URLs :D
xterm*charClass: 33:48,36-47:48,58-59:48,61:48,63-64:48,95:48,126:48

*customization: -color
XTerm*termName:  xterm-256color

xterm*rightScrollBar: false
xterm*ScrollBar: false

XTerm*selectToClipboard: true

! hard contrast: *background: #1d2021
*background: #282828
! soft contrast: *background: #32302f
*foreground: #ebdbb2
! Black + DarkGrey
*color0:  #282828
*color8:  #928374
! DarkRed + Red
*color1:  #cc241d
*color9:  #fb4934
! DarkGreen + Green
*color2:  #98971a
*color10: #b8bb26
! DarkYellow + Yellow
*color3:  #d79921
*color11: #fabd2f
! DarkBlue + Blue
*color4:  #458588
*color12: #83a598
! DarkMagenta + Magenta
*color5:  #b16286
*color13: #d3869b
! DarkCyan + Cyan
*color6:  #689d6a
*color14: #8ec07c
! LightGrey + White
*color7:  #a89984
*color15: #ebdbb2
```

In the xterm running the 256color.pl script show following:

[image]

It seems like this is all that I need.  Am I missing something?  Also my configs can be found at:

https://github.com/sittim/configs

NOTE:  I use nvim, so for configuration look at the .nvimrc, but doing some testing the colours are the same for NVIM and VIM.

Comment: It looks like you are using the solarized colorscheme. As pointed out on the homepage, you should consider changing your terminal emulator colors to solarized (so that the black on your test images is no longer black but the solarized equivalent).

Comment: What's wrong with gnome-terminal? Don't fix it if it ain't broke.

Comment: @carpetsmoker the comment is to  change the terminal emulator colors to solarized not the terminal emulator itself!